# Glassfish Server v2ur2 deployment failed

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, glassfish

Currently I maintain a project that uses the following software:

Glassfish Server v2ur2
Java 1.6
Metro 2.1.1

In this project the following technologies are used:

EJB 3
JAX-WS 2.0
JAXB 2.0

At the beginning of this project some web services were created with the following example configuration:

```
package pt.integration;

<import section>

@WebService(wsdlLocation="META-INF/wsdl/Requeriment/Requeriment.wsdl")
@SchemaValidation
@Stateless
@HandlerChain(file = "RequerimentService_handler.xml")
@Interceptors(pt.integration.RequerimentServiceInterceptor.class)
public class Requeriment {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "requirement")
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public RequerimentReturn requirement(
                            @WebParam(name = "field1") String field1,
                            @WebParam(name = "field2") String field2
                        ) throws RequerimentException {

        // WebService Implementation

       }
    }
```

When these services were deployed to the Glassfish Server v2ur2, the deploy was finish with success.

However there was a need to change a service to add another "@WebParam (name = "field3") String field3".
After this change when I deploy the service,the service is not immediately available. In the logs I have the following information:

```
[#|2017-01-06T17:15:13.258+0000|SEVERE|sun-  appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-9090-4;_RequestID=9229dfac-c7ae-481d-a666-6d930637668e;|Cannot initialize endpoint  : error is : class pt.integration.Requeriment do not have a property of the name field3|#]
```

To have the service available I have to deploy several times at random (one, twice, three times...) until it becomes available.

On the other hand, if I remove the new "@WebParam (name = "field3") String field3" the service deploy is done on the first operation.

Has anyone had this problem or any similar situation.

Thanks in advance.

LP

Comment: doesnt that mean that you are calling the service without the required attributes? Did you adapt the xml file? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jws/WebParam.html

Comment: Yes. When I modified the method signature I changed the appropriate xml schema.

Comment: Maybe deliver a minimal runnable example. I can't reproduce this behaviour

Comment: I found the problem. I have similar names for three webmethods in same package. Thanks for the help.